# How to divide single partition into two different partitions in PostgreSQL and then drop single partitioning

Tags: postgresql

I have one range partition from 2020/01/01 and 2020/06/01
I want to move this to two different partitions i.e 2020/01/01 to 2020/03/31 and 2nd partition from 2020/04/01 to 2020/06/01

how I can achieve as it not allow me to create two partition in same date range and then move data as it say "violates partition rule"

Comment: Just ```DETACH``` this partition, create two smaller on it's place, and then reinsert data from detached partition into main table.

Comment: yes done it in this way already. thanks for help anyway. I posted same answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can detach partition like that

```
ALTER TABLE "eMAR" Detach PARTITION "eMAR_default";
```

then can create any partitons like that

```
CREATE TABLE "eMAR_inBw" PARTITION OF public."eMAR" 
FOR VALUES FROM ('2016-04-17 20:00:00') TO ('2016-06-17 20:00:00');
```

and then can move data from detached partitions like that

```
insert into "eMAR_inBw"
    select * from "eMAR_default" where "MedDateTime" >= '2016-04-17 20:00:00' and "MedDateTime"  <= '2016-06-17 20:00:00'
```

and then you can delete the old partition as well if not required